# r Remove parts of column name after certain characters

Tags: r

I have a large data set with thousands of columns. The column names include various unwanted characters as follows:

```
col1_3x_xxx
col2_3y_xyz
col3_3z_zyx
```

I would like to remove all character strings starting with "_3" from all column names to be left with clean:

```
col1
col2
col3
```

What is the most efficient way to do this for 5000+ columns?

Comment: `names(your_data) = gsub(pattern = "_3*", replacement = "", x = names(your_data))`

Comment: Also, please don't use the RStudio tag unless your question concerns RStudio. (You wouldn't use a Microsoft Word tag for a grammar question just because you're using Word to write something.)

Comment: You can also use: `sapply(strsplit(names(df), "_3"), \`[[\`, 1)`.

Comment: @Gregor I think you need a `.` in `"_3.*"` or else you're looking for a 3 repeated 0 or more times, and @pynewbie if you're look for efficiency with 5000+ columns, there are _milliseconds_ to be gained by adding `perl = TRUE`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We can use `sub`

```
sub("_3.*", "", df1[,1])
#[1] "col1" "col2" "col3"
```

Comment: I had success by replacing the object "df1[,1]" with "colnames(df1)".

Comment: @ToddD. Good to know.  I think the OP wanted to do that after we get the substring

Comment: is there a possible `dplyr` version of this?

Comment: @dre  Use `strr_remove` i.e. `df1 %>% mutate(col = str_remove(col, '_3.*'))`

Answer (score 19):

certainly late for this answer, but just in case someone is looking for a solution

```
colnames(df1)[col] <-  sub("_3.*", "", colnames(df1)[col])
```

And if you have multiple columns :

```
for ( col in 1:ncol(df1)){
    colnames(df1)[col] <-  sub("_3.*", "", colnames(df1)[col])
}
```

Answer (score 5):

We can try the `str_extract` with regular expression pattern `"^[^_]+(?=_)"`:

```
stringr::str_extract(c("col1_3x_xxx", "col2_3y_xyz", "col3_3z_zyx"), "^[^_]+(?=_)")
[1] "col1" "col2" "col3"
```

where in the pattern:

> The first `^` matches the beginning of the string; `[^_]+` matches one
>   or more non `_` character, `^_` means any character but `_`. `(?=...)`
>   stands for lookahead, so we are looking for pattern ahead of `_`.

Comment: No need for the non-capture group: `str_extract(cols, "^[^_]+")`. Pretty much the same speed as Gregor's suggestion: `sub(pattern = "_3.*", replacement = "", x = cols, perl = TRUE)`

Answer (score 3):

For someone looking for a pipeable solution (like I was), use `dplyr::rename_with` and `stringr::str_remove`:

```
  tibble(
    col1_3x_xxx = rnorm(3),
    col2_3y_xyz = rnorm(3),
    col3_3z_zyx = rnorm(3)
  ) %>% 
  rename_with(~ str_remove(., "_3.*"), everything())

# A tibble: 3 × 3
   col1  col2    col3
  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 0.819 0.674  2.06  
2 0.597 0.554 -0.0586
3 0.490 0.878  0.708
```

Obs: for those who thought of `rename_all()`, it has been superseded by `rename_with()` (as well as `rename_if()`, `rename_at()`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
names(df) = gsub(pattern = "_3.*", replacement = "", x = names(df))
```