# Removing special characters from column names in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, data-cleaning

I have a dataset where some of the columns have special characters. I want to clean this dataset and remove these special characters from all the columns that have them.
A subset of the column names is below:

```
Crorf64[,1]
ADF3
DF41c[,1]
AGGF3[,1]
SRGHJ
```

My desired output is:

```
Crorf64
ADF3
DF41c
AGGF3
SRGHJ
```

My attempt to remove the parts of the column names with the special characters is below,
using this answer as a guide https://stackoverflow.com/a/37801926/17054028:

```
training%>%
  mutate(col=str_remove_all(col,"[.*"))
```

I get an error when I use this:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `col = str_remove_all(col, "[.*")`.
Caused by error in `stri_replace_all_regex()`:
! argument `str` should be a character vector (or an object coercible to)
```

Any other alternatives to perform this task are welcome.

Comment: Escape the `[` `\\[.*`

Comment: @GKi I used it ```training%>%
  mutate(col=str_remove_all(col,"\\[.*"))``` but now I am geeting an error it says ```Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `col = str_remove_all(col, "\\[.*")`.
Caused by error in `stri_replace_all_regex()`:
! argument `str` should be a character vector (or an object coercible to)```

Comment: Maybe try: `sub("\\[.*", "", c("Crorf64[,1]", "ADF3"))` ?

Comment: And `stringr::str_remove_all(c("Crorf64[,1]", "ADF3"), "\\[.*")` works also.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it might be the same issue as in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75918861/how-do-i-remove-special-characters-found-on-column-names-in-r/75918987#75918987) so try preventing the creation of these special characters in the first place.

If they were created by a function that returns a matrix (such as `scale()`), note that `[,1]` is not actually part of the column name - it just indicates that the column is actually a matrix:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  Crorf64 = 1,
  ADF3 = 2
)

# add brackets to column name
df <- df |> 
  mutate(across(1, scale))

df
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>   Crorf64[,1]  ADF3
#>         <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1         NaN     2

df |> colnames()
#> [1] "Crorf64" "ADF3"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

If you can't address this issue earlier in your pipeline, you can extract the column from the matrix after the fact like so:

```r
df |> 
  mutate(across(1, \(x) x[,1]))
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>   Crorf64  ADF3
#>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     NaN     2
```